# jQuery prevent text field from losing focus unless user clicks outside

Tags: jquery, focus, textfield

I have a template with a full screen slide show that makes a text field lose focus on mobile devices.. I want to know if there is a fix that can prevent the field lose focus unless the user clicks outside the field..

I have browsed the other questions but found nothing close to what I need.. I appreciate any reply.. Thank You..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you searching something like this? this function gives focus to your input after every click on the body

```
$("body").click(function(){
        $("#yourinput").focus();  
    });
```

**update with correct solution**

working fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/JJLN8/2/

check if the element with focus is an input, if yes change focus else remain in the last input selected. click in the red area that is the body to see that the focus remain in the input

```
var lstfocus=$("input")[0];
$("body").click(function(){
    if ($(':focus').is("input")    ){
          lstfocus= $(':focus');
    }
    lstfocus.focus();    
});
```

css

```
div{width:200px;height:200px; background-color:red}
```

html

```
<div>
    <input type="text"  /><br/>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
 </div>
```

Comment: No, exactly the opposite. When a user selects the textfield, the field should never lose focus unless the user clicks on anything outside the text field..

Comment: Thank you.. It's a glitch of some sort and I need the website to work until I find what is causing this..

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with the glitch?

Comment: No I mean it could be anything.. I need some generic fix to prevent anything from making the textfield lose focus, unless the user clicks outside..

Comment: I'm on the right track now, thank you very much! I'll go test it on my site.